# Hironaka 1964 theorem in the context of S. Watanabe 2009 book

Tags: statistics, algebraic-geometry

I am trying to read the following book of S. Watanabe: "Algebraic Geometry and Statistical Learning Theory".

More particularly, I am currently interested in chapter 2 and Hironaka (1964) theorem on resolution of singularities. I am "only" aiming at mastering the result of this theorem and its utilization in the context of Watanabe book. For the moment, I am finding this somehow difficult, and I find the presentation in Watanabe book a bit quick. I was wondering if people could suggest me more pedagogic references on this subject.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your background? As far as I know the best modern reference on Hironaka's theorem is Koll\'ar's book "Lectures on resolution of singularities", but that might not be suitable for a reader who is not already pretty familiar with algebraic geometry.

Comment: Grothendieck confessed that he had not checked the desingularization proof when he gave the speech accompanying the award of the Fields medal to Hironaka for that result. And Grothendieck **was** "already pretty familiar with algebraic geometry" , in the (as usual) excellent formulation of @Asal ...

Comment: Thanks. I have a background in mathematical statistics but not in algebraic geometry. I should also emphasize that I do not aim at studying the proof of the theorem. I would just like to understand the statement, and the utilization in some simple examples (e.g. examples 2.7 and 2.8 in the book of Watanabe 2009).

Comment: Dear user144871, for a presentation that goes into a great amount of detail, yet is still aimed at those who are not necessarily experts, one could try Hauser's expository paper http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2003-40-03/S0273-0979-03-00982-0/S0273-0979-03-00982-0.pdf. Glancing at that paper, it seems curiously difficult to find a clear statement of the result, but perhaps you might find it helpful.

Comment: Ok, I had a look at the article. The intuition at the beginning helps me, but after it gets more advanced and oriented towards the proof. Thanks for this in any case. If other references are proposed, I am still interested.